# How to make a distinction between static methods and instance methods when mocking a class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I came across a bug in production, even though it should have been tested by the unit tests.

```
class Stage2TaskView(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        json_data = json.loads(request.data)
        news_url_string = json_data['news_url_string']
        OpenCalais().generate_tags_for_news(news_url_string) // ?
        return "", 201
```

This used to be a static:

```
OpenCalais.generate_tags_for_news(news_url_string)
```

But then I changed the method and removed the static decorator.
But I forgot to change that line to

```
OpenCalais().generate_tags_for_news(news_url_string)
```

The test doesn't see it though.  How can I test this in future?

```
@mock.patch('news.opencalais.opencalais.OpenCalais.generate_tags_for_news')
def test_url_stage2_points_to_correct_class(self, mo):
    rv = self.client.post('/worker/stage-2', data=json.dumps({'news_url_string': 'x'}))
    self.assertEqual(rv.status_code, 201)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) is your fried! Use `autospec=True` in patch decorator will check the complete signature:

```
class A():
    def no_static_method(self):
        pass

with patch(__name__+'.A.no_static_method', autospec=True):
    A.no_static_method()
```

will raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/damico/PycharmProjects/mock_import/autospec.py", line 9, in <module>
    A.no_static_method()
TypeError: unbound method no_static_method() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Ah thats it. You have helped me on so many mock questions. Can't thank you enough :)